# no kernel image is available for execution on the device Fatal Python error: Aborted

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run yolov4 code in this repo: https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite
And I installed python 3.7 and all requirements and cuda and cudnn.
By the log, the cudnn and cuda is installed well, but there is error of "no kernel image is available for execution on the device" what is this error? is it related in cuda or cudnn version error?

Python: 3.7.9, CUDA: 10.1, Tensorflow:2.3.0rc0, Tensorflow-GPU:not installed, CUDNN:7.5.0, OS: Windows10(x64)

```
py -3.7 save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-416-tflite --input_size 416 --model yolov4 --framework tflite
2020-09-03 11:02:05.897607: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:09.504648: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:09.997508: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.2415GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 13.41GiB/s
2020-09-03 11:02:10.017273: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.036505: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.059534: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.074749: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.094710: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.115167: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.140633: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.148636: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-03 11:02:10.155846: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-03 11:02:10.188413: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x295adc030a0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-03 11:02:10.199421: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-03 11:02:10.207675: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.2415GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 13.41GiB/s
2020-09-03 11:02:10.222939: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.231890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.241896: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.250393: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.260177: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.268644: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.278132: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-09-03 11:02:10.286635: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-03 11:02:10.380510: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-03 11:02:10.388703: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0
2020-09-03 11:02:10.394562: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N
2020-09-03 11:02:10.402323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1464 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-09-03 11:02:10.429701: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x295ae120140 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-03 11:02:10.441631: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce 940MX, Compute Capability 5.0
2020-09-03 11:02:10.619742: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

Comment: it seems like cuda or cudnn version error: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30665

Comment: Can you add Cuda and CuDNN version and update your question?

Comment: @Aniket Bote, I just added.. thx. I checked If I install tensorflow 2.1.0, this error is resolved but If I install tensorflow >2.3.0, this error revived. And My wanted git repo requires tensorflow >2.3.0.  I think this is related Cuda and CuDNN version and I'll try other versions(lower or higher...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that the pre-built binary used in tensorflow, does not support the SM version (compute capability) supported by your actual hardware.

You can refer to below link for supported combinations:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

Based on this, both 2.1.0 and 2.3.0 require CUDNN 7.4 and CUDA 10.1. You should try with these supported combinations.

[2.3.0 release/rc2/rc0 specific] from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.3.0 - `TF 2.3 includes PTX kernels only for compute capability 7.0 to reduce the TF pip binary size. Earlier releases included PTX for a variety of older compute capabilities.`

Comment: thanks, I reinstalled CUDNN to 7.4 and CUDA 10.1 but it still has same error. I heard it is a new issue of TF 2.3.0 for some GPUS. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41990   Just hoping it will resolved someday... I should downgrade to TF 2.2 because TF 2.2 works well with CUDNN 7.4 and CUDA 10.1...

Comment: It says... https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42467, TF 2.3 includes PTX kernels only for compute capability 7.0 to reduce the TF pip binary size. Earlier releases included PTX for a variety of older compute capabilities. So some graphic card is not usable for TF 2.3 today... thanks.